# Undefined symbols after installing AFNetworking with Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking, cocoapods

Can anybody help me with this, its driving me crazy. I looked at every post I could find with a similar issue, and none of it worked.

I installed `AFNetworking 3.0` in my project with `Cocoapods`, it installed, I see the AFNetworking pod in my project. Whenever I try to build I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPSessionManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Server.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Thanks.  You should add your edit as an answer and mark it as solved.  This fixed my problem as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem after further investigating.

I added `libAFNetworking.a` in `Project->Build Phases->Link Binary With Librarys`

It is now compiling correctly.